# Create a transaction without cleos nor eosjs

Tags: transactions, rpc

Is there a way to push a signed transaction  via CURL or WGET or something similar?  I can't use cleos, nodeos, nor eosjs, because I can't exec anything in the environment I'm working with.

I'm trying to understand how to sign a transaction and push it via CURL.  Once I understand those steps, it would be really easy to do in any programming language, but I haven't found any documentation other than "use eosjs".

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well eosjs would be easiest to create a serialized trx (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/master/src/eosjs-serialize.ts) which you can then push by POST request to the RPC https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/push_transaction

Answer (score 0):

as @Nat was suggesting, use a system that has eosjs and create the trx offline (so to speak)
then use that trx created offline in the system where you do not have eosjs

here's an article that explain how to create and offline trx
https://blog.softwaremill.com/creating-offline-eos-transaction-without-cleos-5c48d429101d

Comment: I can't use eosjs in that environment.

Comment: the suggested answer is saying to use eosjs on a different machine not on the same one